# Installing ruby <2.3 rbenv in fedora workstation 34

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedora, rbenv

I've recently loaded up Fedora as my main dev environment.

However, I'm having issues installing ruby versions <2.3.

I've installed rbenv and ruby 3.0.2 just to check that everything works, here is my output and logs.

```
➜  ~ rbenv install 2.2.6              
Downloading ruby-2.2.6.tar.bz2...-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.6.tar.bz2

Installing ruby-2.2.6...

WARNING: ruby-2.2.6 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.


BUILD FAILED (Fedora 34 using ruby-build 20210726-1-gcf9a6fc)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20210730103309.64945.5oJnxZ
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20210730103309.64945.log

Last 10 log lines:
linking shared-object bigdecimal.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20210730103309.64945.5oJnxZ/ruby-2.2.6/ext/bigdecimal'
linking shared-object nkf.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20210730103309.64945.5oJnxZ/ruby-2.2.6/ext/nkf'
linking shared-object date_core.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20210730103309.64945.5oJnxZ/ruby-2.2.6/ext/date'
linking shared-object ripper.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20210730103309.64945.5oJnxZ/ruby-2.2.6/ext/ripper'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ruby-build.20210730103309.64945.5oJnxZ/ruby-2.2.6'
make: *** [uncommon.mk:189: build-ext] Error 2
```

Here are the logs https://pastebin.com/KHCQjAsA

Comment: can you share `/tmp/ruby-build.20210730103309.64945.log` please ?

Comment: I've added the logs @Sumak into a pastebin as they exceeded the limit of the body

Comment: The error messages are all about openssl. See workarounds like [this](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1353#issuecomment-573414540).

Comment: I'm not using homebrew I installed rbenv from source @TomLord

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
apt install libssl1.0-dev


CC=$(which gcc-6) rbenv install 2.2.6
```

Comment: I'm on fedora which uses `dnf` not `apt`

Comment: Right, I missed that